# C# Web site using System.Threading cannot get user name

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
using System.Threading;
Response.Write(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
```

It returns nothing. This code works fine on web sites both on the server and in my IDE VS2010.

Comment: "This code works fine on web sites both on the server and in my IDE VS2010." so where doesn't it work fine?

Comment: It doesn't work on my new web site. I have tied it in an aspx page that would store the value in Session and on the code behind on one of the user input pages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the Web.comfig file. Authentication was set to “Forms”. Resetting to “Windows” returned the users name and Domain.